# Opening .DBF files as read-only with the dbf Python module

Tags: python, dbf

First of all, the dbf module is great. I've been using it with great success.

I'm trying to open a dbf file on a network share which is a read-only file system. When I try to open it like this, I get an error which says that the .dbf file is read-only.

```
thisTable = dbf.Table('/volumes/readOnlyVolume/thisFile.dbf')
thisTable.open()
```

Looking at the documentation, it looks like there's a way to open a table in read-only mode, but I can't figure it out. If you have a second, would you be able to help me out?

Thanks!
Kyle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cool, thanks!  :)

At this point, you need to specify the open mode when you call `thisTable.open()`, like this:

```
thisTable.open(mode='read-only')
```

or

```
thisTable.open(mode=dbf.READ_ONLY)
```

Oh, and here's the [PyPI link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) to the module.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [this module](http://dbfpy.sourceforge.net/), the magic incantation to open read only is:

```
dbf1 = Dbf()
dbf1.openFile('county.dbf', readOnly=1)
```

Hope that helped, if not, do add more detail to your question.